# Why is the Java scanner skipping over one of the user prompt in a while statement, nested in the for loop?

Tags: java

The scanner is not prompting the user for an input in the second while statement, which is nested in the for loop. Why? Any solutions?

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ComputeGpa
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        { 
            char grade = '\0';
            int credits = 0;
            String aGrade = "";

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            Gpa gpas = new Gpa();

            int numCourses = 0;
            while(numCourses <= 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter number of courses: ");
                numCourses = in.nextInt();
                if(numCourses <= 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number of courses - must be greater than 0!");
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++)
            {
                while(aGrade.length() != 1)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter grade (one character): ");
                    aGrade = in.next();
                    grade = aGrade.charAt(0);
                    if(aGrade.length() != 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid grade - must be exactly one character");
                    }
                }

                while((credits < 0) || (credits > 9))// this is the while statement I have
                    problems with
                    {
                    System.out.print("Enter credits: ");
                    credits = in.nextInt();
                    if((credits <  0) || (credits > 9))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid credits - must be between 0 and 9");
                    }
                    gpas.addTotals(grade, credits);
                    }
            }

            System.out.printf("GPA: %.2f", gpas.calcGpa()); 

        }        
    }
```

The condition I'm trying to validate is that the user must enter a number between 0 and 9, inclusively.

I then get a calculated value of "NaN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `while` loop to a `do ... while` loop, because you want the loop ALWAYS to run on the first time through, but you also want the condition to be checked at the end of the loop.

Comment: I thought the while and do loops could be used interchangeably, but thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while((credits < 0) || (credits < 9))
```

to

```
while((credits < 0) || (credits > 9))
```

Side note: "inclusive" means that you would want to include 0 and 9 as allowable credit values. But that's not what you have here, since you're using < instead of <= and > instead of >=.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to while((credits <= 0) || (credits > 9)) since you have initialized credits to '0'.Just add this

```
 while((credits <= 0) || (credits > 9))// this is the while statement I have
                                              //problems with
      {
        System.out.print("Enter credits: ");
        credits = in.nextInt();
        if((credits <  0) || (credits > 9))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid credits - must be between 0 and 9");
        }
        if(credits == 0)
            break;

     //   gpas.addTotals(grade, credits);
      }
```

credits will accept 0 - 9 and will not ask user again

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify last while loop to suit your needs , hope this code segment helps you.

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter credits: ");
    credits = in.nextInt();
    if ((credits < 0) || (credits > 9)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid credits - must be between 0 and 9");
    }else{
        gpas.addTotals(grade, credits);
        }
} while ((credits < 0) || (credits > 9));
```